# Iterate over part of String in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

Why in the world are Swift String operations so complex and tiresome to work with?

I have to iterate over a String in reverse but ignoring the first char. Now this could be done like following:

```
var firstTime = true
for i in textBefore.characters.reversed() {
  if firstTime {
     firstTime = false
  } else {
      if String(i).personalFunction() {
        // something
      } else {
        // something else
      }
  }
}
```

But really I just want to do something like:

```
textBefore = textBefore.characters.reversed() 
for i in 1...textBefore.characters.count {
  if textBefore.get(i).personalFunction() {
    // something
  } else {
    // something else
  }
}
```

So why can't we get index as int. And why is textBefore.characters.reversed() not a String or simply have String have a reverse function. All these issues just makes it so frustrating to work with Strings in Swift and makes us do stupid stuff as converting a String to an array of chars :S or stuff like my proposed solution above... Also we can't make for loops in the old fashion... I simply need some Swift guru to point my brain in the right direction for this stuff.

Comment: To the "why," accessing a character in a string is not O(1) because of UTF-8 decoding. In the worst case it's O(n). Most languages give you direct access to bytes (ignoring UTF-8 and dramatically complicating things and injecting subtle bugs when multi-byte characters show up), or they work in a much less space-efficient data structure. Anything that is O(1) but uses less than 4-bytes per character (UTF-16 for instance) opens the door to surprising corner cases when you work in non Latin languages.

Comment: (That said, if Swift wants to be a scripting language, and it says it does, it's going to need to develop a better interface to parts of Strings. It's not that Swift has the best solution; it's just that most languages ignore most of the problem and make things easy in simple cases, but buggy in any other case.)

Comment: @RobNapier Well that makes sense, but in most cases these issues are not something we have problem with. Now Swift gives issues for 95% of developers and 5% wont have issues they otherwise would have had to make workaround for. And out of those 95% ~20% or something might end up making workarounds (extension etc.) to make it work properly.

Comment: In my experience from other languages (such as Go and C++), a lot of people actually have these problems. They just don't *realize* they have this problem until they localize their app to Chinese or Turkish or Thai and everything blows up. (And Apple deeply wants you to localize your apps to many cultures, which most programming languages don't concern themselves with.) Apple forces you to think about localization much earlier than any other ecosystem I've worked with.

Comment: @RobNapier Well that is actually true, but again most apps etc. actually don't go global. But it wil ease the process for those that does.

Comment: And don't forget: some of the craziest Unicode complexities you'll ever encounter come from emoji (try to decide the "length" of ‍‍‍). Lots of folks don't care about working in Arabic, but it seems *everyone* wants emoji… :)

Comment: @RobNapier Haha thats true ;)

Comment: My understanding is the Swift team is also pretty unhappy with the way Strings currently work. They're slated for re-examination for Swift 4 (if they get to it) so there could be some improvements in the near future: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I'll be crossing my fingers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string.characters` is a collection of characters.
 Use `reversed()` to access the elements in reverse order, and`dropFirst()` to skip the initial element of the reversed collection:

```
let string = "ab"

for ch in string.characters.reversed().dropFirst() {
    print(ch)
    // `ch` is a Character. Use `String(ch)` if you need a String.
}
```

Output:

```
b

a
```

Comment: Very nice solution to this.

Comment: And thanks a ton, but I still feel that all the usual String function you would expect are lacking and working completely different from most other languages...

Comment: @Warpzit: I see, you want to skip the first element of the reversed string, not of the initial string, I had misunderstood that. – Yes, strings in Swift may be difficult, but what other language supports full Unicode support? With `""` or `""` being a *single character*? My rule of thumb is: treat strings a sequences and iterate over them. Avoid subscripting with explicit indices (which is "expensive").

Comment: @Warpzit: I have updated the example to demonstrate the Unicode features better. But Rob has already explained the situation much better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do something like your second one. After you enter the `for`, you can just get the index directly from the string.  In Swift, a string is just an array of characters.

```
textBefore = String(textBefore.characters.reversed())
for i in 1...textBefore.characters.count {
  if textBefore[i].personalFunction() {
    // something
  } else {
    // something else
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the first line cast in `String()`, see my edit.  But, Martin's answer is better anyway :p

Comment: I can't convert textBefore[i] to String. Will give subscript warning.